# POST request body which has nested JSON

Tags: java, rest, automated-tests, rest-assured

I am succefully able to sent
"sticky_agent": [
{
"enable": true,
"time": "5d"
}
],
in my request body but I need to send it like this
"sticky_agent":
{
"enable": true,
"time": "5d"
},

List<Sticky_agent> stickyList = new ArrayList<>();
stickyList.add(new Sticky_agent(true, "5d"));

what changes I should make here

Comment: Sticky_agent data = new Sticky_agent(true, "5d"); would be enough dont need to create arraylist

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

key: [{key:value, key:value}]

The Square brackets [] sometimes means the array or list, and the element is the content wrapped in the Curly bracket {}.

If you want to remove the [], just define the attribute as a struct not an array or list. e.g:

```
public class Demo {

     private StickyAgent stickyAgent;

     public String toJsonString(){
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
     }

    @Data
    public class StickyAgent {
        private boolean enable;
        private String time;
    }
}
```